# Load AngularJS app async

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, dependency-injection

I'm trying to load an AngularJS app asynchronously, but I fear that this might just not be possible.

I've mostly followed the examples of [this guide by CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/), unfortunately without any success.

The closes attempt was to first load jQuery only, and then use it to load other scripts with an ajax call:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery.cachedScript = function( url, options ) {
            options = $.extend( options || {}, {
              dataType: "script",
              cache: true,
              url: url
            });

            return jQuery.ajax( options );
        };
        $.cachedScript( "https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular.min.js" )
        .done(function() {
            return $.cachedScript( "scripts/vendor.js")
        })
        .done(function() {
            $.cachedScript( "scripts/app.js", { cache : false } );
        });
</script>
```

In this way all scripts are loaded correctly. However, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…0c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A463)
```

I've then tried this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery.cachedScript = function( url, options ) {
            options = $.extend( options || {}, {
              dataType: "script",
              cache: true,
              url: url
            });

            return jQuery.ajax( options );
        };
        $.cachedScript( "scripts/app.js", { cache : false } );

</script>
```

But the same error is thrown.

It seems that the problem is caused by the fact that angularjs is loaded before the `app.js` file, which however seems quite strange.

Thus the question, isn't it possible to load angularjs files async?

PS
I did also try other ways, but they won't work as the order in which files must be loaded is mandatory (depencencies...).

For example, I've also tried the html `async` attribute:

```
<script async src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script async src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script async src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script async src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

But that fails as in this way scripts are loaded in an unpredictable order.

I've also tried to manually inject the links (without the async attribute)

```
(function() {
    var urls = [
        "scripts/app.js",
        "scripts/vendor.js",
        "https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular.min.js",
        "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js",
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = false;
        po.src = urls[i];
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    }
})();
```

But still without success, as they are still loaded in an unpredictable order.

Comment: Are you using the `ng-app` directive?

Comment: Yes, should I remove it?

Comment: I made an answer, please, have a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you said, you're using the `ng-app` directive, when angular parses the DOM in order to find the `ngApp` directive it tries to automatically bootstrap the application and, because the `app.js` isn't loaded yet, angular throws.

So, you need to remove that attribute and, in your `app.js` add the following lines:

`angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('ngAppContainer'), ['app']);`

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to solve the problem in development, but when I build the production version, with minified code, I get this error: `Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=app
    at Error (native)`. I've checked the app.js file and the module is there, am I missing something else?